# AWS ec2 as dns server is not working

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, amazon-web-services

I have beeing trying to set a DNS nameserver on Amazon Ubuntu resolv.conf .

To do that, I have followed the steps :

```
sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
```

Added following entries:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Did the updates:

```
sudo resolvconf --enable-updates
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Finally verified the settings :

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

To make sure AWS instance allows the ports , I had opened all UDP and TCP connections from every where.

Now, when I set my DNS server to be my AWS public IP , it does not reoslve any address and no connection.

**Edit:**
I installed dnsmasq  and configured with name server options as well.

I did disable resolv, but still unable to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to get my dnsmasq working by listening to both local and private ip.

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1,172.31.x.x
bind-dynamic
bogus-priv
domain-needed
log-facility=-
local-ttl=60
```